# Cannot get result between datetime with 2 given dates

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want get a result between datetime but have been unsuccessful.

This problem has troubled me for a long time.
I hope to get expert answers.

My PHP looks like this:

```
$fromdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fromdate']);    
$fromdate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $fromdate);    
$fromdate = date_format($fromdate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$todate= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['todate']);    
$todate= date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $todate);    
$todate= date_format($todate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');    

$qtotal = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM pos WHERE status=1 and dateline >= '".$fromdate."' AND dateline < '".$todate."'");    
while ($ltotal = mysql_fetch_array($qtotal)){       
    $total = $ltotal['total'];    
}
echo $total;
```

I can't get any result on the php side, but MySQL query works fine.

```
select 
    sum(total) as total 
from pos 
where (status =1 and dateline >= '2015-04-11 00:00:00' 
and dateline < '2015-04-15 18:30:00');
```

dateline type is DATETIME.

Comment: try echo this query SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM pos WHERE status=1 and dateline >= '".$fromdate."' AND dateline < '".$todate."'" and run in your sql ui or phpmyadmin and check it is retriving any record?

Comment: Use `BETWEEN` : `WHERE status =1 AND dateline BETWEEN '2015-04-11' 
AND  '2015-04-15 18:30:00'`

Comment: @Chlam what are you passing to `fromdate` and `todate` in url ?

Comment: Date Format
eg: 11/04/2015 17:45:05 (d/m/Y H:i:s)

Comment: This query should and it is working. Are you sure you have records that match this query? **[Can you show us a non-working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6f20/1)?**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to help, I had solve my problem by this way...
;I'm really confused why this can be used =.=

```
$strtodate= strtotime($todate);
$strfromdate= strtotime($fromdate);

$fromdate = "".date('Y',$strfromdate)."-".date('m',$strfromdate)."-".date('d',$strfromdate)." ".date('H',$strfromdate).":".date('i',$strfromdate).":".date('s',$strfromdate)."";
$todate = "".date('Y',$strtodate)."-".date('m',$strtodate)."-".date('d',$strtodate)." ".date('H',$strtodate).":".date('i',$strtodate).":".date('s',$strtodate)."";

$qtotal = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM pos WHERE (status=1 AND dateline >= '$fromdate' AND dateline < '$todate')");
```